# Plotting time ranges in seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, visualization, seaborn

I am trying to visualize the relationship between two classes of data (users and IP addresses) over time. I was get to *almost* the visualization I wanted in seaborn using `boxplot` but I can't seem to find anyway to convince seaborn to render the full min to max as the box width, it will only show it as the whiskers.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

# What I would like to display is a box for each time a user was using an IP address. 
demo = pd.DataFrame([
    {'id' : 'range1', 'user' : 'UserA', 'ip' : 'IP1', 'minTs' : 1000, 'maxTs' : 2000},
    {'id' : 'range2', 'user' : 'UserA', 'ip' : 'IP2', 'minTs' : 1800, 'maxTs' : 3000},
    # ideally this second range would displayed as seperate box though I can live with overall min/max
    {'id' : 'range3', 'user' : 'UserA', 'ip' : 'IP2', 'minTs' : 5000, 'maxTs' : 6000},
    {'id' : 'range4', 'user' : 'UserB', 'ip' : 'IP1', 'minTs' : 200, 'maxTs' : 4000},
    {'id' : 'range5', 'user' : 'UserB', 'ip' : 'IP3', 'minTs' : 3000, 'maxTs' : 4000},
])
```

```py
# to plot this using box plots we explode each min/max time into it's own row so the boxplot can figure 
# out the ranges and quantiles of my ranges
demoMinMax = pd.concat([
    demo[['ip', 'user', 'minTs']].rename(columns = {'minTs' : 'time'}),
    demo[['ip', 'user', 'maxTs']].rename(columns = {'maxTs' : 'time'}),
]).sort_values(["user", "ip", "time"]).reset_index()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14, 4));
sns.boxplot(
    x="time", y="user", hue ='ip', data=demoMinMax, 
    whis = 100, 
    linewidth=5,
    fliersize = 0, 
    boxprops=dict(alpha=.3),
    notch=None, 
    dodge =False, 
    palette='bright'
);
ax.xaxis.grid(True);
ax.set(ylabel="");

ax.legend(loc='upper right');
```

The above produces this image (I have widened the lines to make it easier to see). If I could just get the boxes to where the whiskers are I would be satisfied.
[image: Current Picture]

Here is a badly photoshopped version of the ideal image. I didn't attempt any 'alpha blending' so I just used notches to show where the ranges overlapped. Note that this has multiple ranges for same IP user combination on the same line, I have a feeling that may be harder and really not fit in the standard libraries.

[image: Ideal Outcome]

If I can't get multiple ranges at same time I would settle for full range min/max like below.

[image: Hoped for Outcome]

I am not married to seaborn or matplotlib, any python library that will play nice with juypter notebooks that can display this would be sufficient.

Comment: If you don't want the box and whiskers, don't use `boxplot()`. Have you tried seaborn's `barplot()`? To create the notch effect, you can split each bar into two bars of unequal lengths. See https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/horizontal_barplot.html for one example of split barplots.

Comment: As far as I can tell `barplot` always plots from 0 to X so I can't draw a range that may start at any point.

Comment: How about using raw polygons in matplotlib? 
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/shapes_and_collections/patch_collection.html#sphx-glr-gallery-shapes-and-collections-patch-collection-py and https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html

Answer (score 1):

It occurred to me that I could just adjust my data so the 25/75% quantiles are where I want the box to be. Turns out that math is really simple to do when we have just min/max. This got the ranges where I wanted. 
I still couldn't get multiple ranges per row so I am using a `stripplot` to show what underlying data is in raw ranges by putting a dot at each end of the range. This is actually better for my use case than multiple ranges so I am going to call this solved.

```py
def returnMaxOnlyIfDeltaLarge(row, minVal, maxVal, minRange = 1):
    delta = row[maxVal] - row[minVal]
    if(delta > minRange):
        return row[maxVal]
    else:
        # we will deduplicate this data later
        return row[minVal]

def getWitnessPoints(pdf, y, hue, minVal, maxVal, outputCol):
    pdf['updatedEnd'] = pdf.apply(lambda r: returnMaxOnlyIfDeltaLarge(r, minVal, maxVal), axis = 1)
    demoMinMax = pd.concat([
        pdf[[y, hue, minVal]].rename(columns = {minVal : outputCol}),
        pdf[[y, hue, 'updatedEnd']].rename(columns = {'updatedEnd' : outputCol}),
    ]).drop_duplicates().sort_values([y, hue, outputCol]).reset_index()
    return demoMinMax

def prepareBoxData(pdf, y, hue, minVal, maxVal, outputCol, plotMarginPercent = 0.02):
    # first consolidate any pairs with more than one range into a single large range
    consolidated = pdf.groupby([y, hue]).agg({minVal : {'' :np.min}, maxVal : {'' : np.max}}).reset_index()
    consolidated.columns = ["".join(x) for x in consolidated.columns.ravel()]

    # Since boxplot can't be convinced to not calculate the IQR lets just adjust the data so the plotted values 
    # are exactly what we want. It turns out to be easy to reverse the calculation for two points and we just double
    # the width of the range around the common center
    consolidated['iqrDelta'] = (consolidated[maxVal] - consolidated[minVal])/2
    consolidated['shiftMin'] = consolidated[minVal] - consolidated['iqrDelta']
    consolidated['shiftMax'] = consolidated[maxVal] + consolidated['iqrDelta']

    # to plot this using box plots we explode each min/max time into it's own row so the boxplot can figure 
    # out the ranges and quantiles to populate the box widths 
    demoMinMax = pd.concat([
        consolidated[[y, hue, 'shiftMin']].rename(columns = {'shiftMin' : outputCol}),
        consolidated[[y, hue, 'shiftMax']].rename(columns = {'shiftMax' : outputCol}),
    ]).sort_values([y, hue, outputCol]).reset_index()

    # since we are altering the data ranges the xaxis limits are going to be way off. We can fix that by looking
    # at the unaltered input data and recalculating the min/max. Add a little margin to keep the display pretty
    overallRange = pdf.agg({minVal : np.min, maxVal : np.max})
    rangeMargin = (overallRange[maxVal] - overallRange[minVal]) * plotMarginPercent
    plotRange = [overallRange[minVal] - rangeMargin, overallRange[maxVal]+rangeMargin]

    return [demoMinMax, plotRange]

demoMinMax, plotRange = prepareBoxData(demo, 'user', 'ip', 'minTs', 'maxTs', 'time')

uniqueUsers = demo['user'].unique().size
uniqueIps = demo['ip'].unique().size

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14, uniqueUsers));
sns.boxplot(
    x="time", y="user", hue ='ip', data=demoMinMax, 
    whis = 0, 
    # disabling linewidth is the key to disabling the whiskers
    linewidth=0,
    fliersize = 0, 
    boxprops=dict(alpha=.3),
    notch=None, 
    dodge =False, 
    palette='bright'
);

minMaxes = getWitnessPoints(demo, 'user', 'ip', 'minTs', 'maxTs', 'time')
sns.stripplot(x="time", y="user", hue ='ip', data=minMaxes.sort_values(['ip', 'user']), 
              dodge =False, palette='bright')

ax.set_xlim(plotRange);

# Get the handles and labels. For this example it'll be 2 tuples
# of length 4 each.
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

# When creating the legend, only use the first two elements
# to effectively remove the last two.
l = plt.legend(handles[0:uniqueIps], labels[0:uniqueIps], loc='upper right')

ax.xaxis.grid(True);
ax.set(ylabel="");
```

[image]